# Effort estimation

Tags: resource-planning

Does the effort calculated in person months using [COCOMO model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COCOMO) include the effort for requirements analysis also? Or is it just calculating the effort required for the design, code and testing only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

COCOMO focuses on what is required to actually build it, not the up-front requirements work. Now, you'll notice that there are varying levels of requirements and constraints and it produces a smaller and smaller estimate as the requirements get more specific, so there may be something to infer there, but the model doesn't attempt to provide that answer.